# Curator for deleting indices older than 30 days or more based on a field that isn’t of type date

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

```
{
 "_index": "user:1494813192000",
 "_type": "fruits",
 "_id": "pbyac5r88-yghe-v1ez-cpgb-sqdjipr54alzgj/tp4oqalbd-bo2v-ikj1-atfq-wezcoeeuf6wiqpt/apple",
 "_score": 1,
 "_routing": "pbyac5r88-yghe-v1ez-cpgb-sqdjipr54alzgj",
 "_source": {
 "numCal": 442,
 "eventTime": 1497315192000,
 "fruitName": "apple"
}
```

This is how the index in my elasticsearch looks like. The eventTime is the current time in ms based on UTC. I would want to use that field to delete my indices using the curator.

This is how my ACTION_FILE.YML looks like

```
actions:
  1:
    action: delete_indices 
    description: >-
      Delete indices older than 45 days (based on index name), for logstash-
      prefixed indices. Ignore the error if the filter does not result in an
      actionable list of indices (ignore_empty_list) and exit cleanly.
    options:
      ignore_empty_list: True
      timeout_override:
      continue_if_exception: False
      disable_action: False
    filters:
    - filtertype: age
      source: field_stats
      field: 'eventTime'
      direction: older
      unit: days
      unit_count: 30
      exclude:
```

Does curator support deleting based on fields that aren't in data format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally answered this question [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/curator-for-deleting-indices-older-than-30-days-or-more-based-on-a-field-that-isnt-of-type-date/89248/2), but include it here as well.

Date and time comparisons work in Curator based on epoch time.  As Elasticsearch stores date entries internally as epoch values, this is why it is usually required to use a field that is stored as a date stamp when using the `field_stats` for comparisons.

However, if the field epoch time, which is properly mapped as a `long` in Elasticsearch, and stores either an epoch, or epoch plus milliseconds (but not decimal), it should work just fine for use with `field_stats`.

For reference, the code that demonstrates this principle is [here](https://github.com/elastic/curator/blob/v5.1.1/curator/indexlist.py#L257-L268)).